# BICC extracting incorrect values

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

There is a PVO that is having incorrect values when extracted using BICC. The values of this PVO in the OTBI have no issue. However, when I extracted that PVO using the BICC, I am getting values like "1.234567E218, (null), 1.234567E-68".

The column is only for numeric values (NUMERIC 50). This column should have values like "3.00E14" or 15-digit values. The values we are getting is larger or unusual.

I've compared this PVO with the same PVO in the other environments but they are the same (other environments dont have this issue). I have no idea where to check since the OTBI is having the correct values, and I think the cause of this error is in the BICC.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do anything on Oracle BICC extracts.
Also would like to suggest that this question should be raised in the Oracle community.